# Join lines between a certain text pattern in Vim

Tags: vim

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
A.
text
text
text


A.
more text

more text

A.
more text
```

I want to join all lines between the "markers" `A.` so that it looks like:

```
A.texttexttext
A.more textmore text
A.more text
```

How can I do this in Vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:%s/\n\(\(A\.$\)\@!.*\)/\1/
```

Substitute a pattern matching:

1. newline,
2. a group containing of

   1. *not* the string `A.` directly followed by end-of-line, then
   2. any character until end of line

with:

- everything matched except the starting newline (i.e. the group above),

and do this globally.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea how that thing works, but it seems to! I will have to dissect it carefully. I also found a work around by joining all the lines and then inserting a new line on "A."

Comment: @vimnoob: See `:help \@!` in Vim for more info on that part. Otherwise it's straight forward, hopefully, with my explanation. A problem with your approach is that if "`A.`" occurs in the text, though not as an isolated marker line, it will be split upon as if it were originally a marker. In practice it might not be a problem (I don't know what your "real" file looks like), but generically it can cause unwanted behavior if one is not aware of this.

Comment: @vimnoob: I read my answer again, and in case you're not familiar with the `:%s///` syntax: it's a "search and replace" syntax in Vim. `:` starts the command, `%` specifies the whole buffer as the range, `s` starts a substitution. `/` is the pattern delimiter (any other character can be used, but `/` is "standard"). The first `/` starts the search pattern, the second the replace pattern, and the third ends it. Trailing modifiers are available to specify case insensitivity, etc. `\1` represents the grabbed group in the search pattern. `:%s/foo/bar/` replaces `foo` with `bar` in the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I just need to research this \@! part as I am familiar with the basic search replace and basic regexp.

Comment: This is a great answer that I keep coming back to, but I have to confess that most of the time I just end up joining all of the lines and then splitting them. I just don't use `\@!` quite often enough to get proficient in its use.

Comment: @DanielAndersson Is it possible to join the lines but to remove the break character `A\.$` after joining the lines ?

Comment: @Reman: The most straight-forward way I immediately think of is running a subsequent global pattern match like `:%s/^A\.//`. The method in the answer does not capture the `^A\.` patterns themselves (rather their absence), so it cannot modify those strings in an obvious way.

Comment: This doesn't work in the general case. Add `B.\nDon't fold\n\n` and it will join that as well

Answer (score 8):

This also works (when the first line starts with `A.`)

```
:v/^A/-1j!
```

Comment: That does work! Nice. +1

Comment: Yay, verily, and two tricks new to me, after the global anti-pattern match (v): the 'j' for join, and the '!' for join without adding a space. Thank you.

Comment: @Miro wow! i salute you sir. if you could explain why it works then super!.. also i had to concatenate the lines with tab character in between... so what i did was to add a s/$/\t/g tab characterat end of every line before issuing above command.. any better way

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution that also works with more more complex input

```
:$s/$/A./ | g/A./,/A./- s/\n\(A\.\)\@!//
:$s/A\.$//
```

1. insert missing `A.` at end of file
2. Delete all newlines in between tags `A.`
3. Delete the closing `A.` tag at the end of file
   *I Had to run this in e separate command, otherwise vim executed it before it had removed newlines. Can probably be solved somehow.

#### Input

```
B.
Don't join


A.
text
text
text


A.
more text

more text

A.
more text
```

#### Output

```
B.
Don't join


A.texttexttext
A.more textmore text
A.more text
```

Comment: What is this first `$` in the line?

Comment: `$` is the address of the last line

Comment: Thanks for adding the colons. It clarified a bit.